# Включить редактирование только добавляемой новой строки JTable

Tags: java, база-данных, jtable

Здравствуйте! Для таблицы `JTable` поставил `isCellEditable` в `false`

```
MyAllDataTable = new JTable(tableModel) {
    //...............
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {               
       return false;
    }
};
```

чтобы не редактировать через нее данные из БД.
Далее по кнопке добавляю в `MyAllDataTable` новую строку:

```
public void NewRowButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Vector<Object> curRow = new Vector<Object>();
    curRow.add("NRow");
    curRow.add("nrow");
    curRow.add("0000");
    curRow.add("nrow@nrow.ru");
    curRow.add("nrow_corp");
    curRow.add("1111");
    data.add(curRow);
    DefaultTableModel myModel = (DefaultTableModel) MyAllDataTable.getModel();
    myModel.newRowsAdded(new TableModelEvent(myModel));
}
```

Как можно включить редактирование у свежедобавленной строчки в `JTable`, а так же добавить функцию редактирования выделенной строки в контекстном меню?

Comment: кто-нибудь может помочь?